# Mapping POJOs to case classes with immutable lists during deserialisation

Tags: java, scala, immutability, case-class, json4s

I am coming from Java background and trying to understand how to model Domain classes/POJOs in Scala.

I am trying to Deserialize JSON response from a RestAPI and my Java POJOs are as follows:

```
@Data
public class ColumnResponse {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String type;
    ...
}
```

k

```
@Data
public class DataSetGetResponse {
    private String id;
    private List<ColumnResponse> columns;
    ...
}
```

Now I have created following Case Classes

```
case class DataSetGetResponse (id: String,
                               columns: List[ColumnResponse]
                              .... )


case class ColumnResponse (id: String,name: String ...)
```

I am trying to use https://sttp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/json.html#json4s library for HTTP communication and json4s for deserialization.

Questions:

1) In the DataSetGetResponse case class, field "columns" is a List.By default this is an immutable list. How the Deserialization library add new DataColumnGetResponse objects to this immutable list? Do I have to declare this as mutable ?

2) There is a field called 'type' field in the ColumnResponse POJO. In Scala 'type' is a reserved keyword.How to handle this case?

Comment: No need to make the list mutable. When adding an element to immutable list a new list is created with the added element. Regarding `type` field just surround it with backtics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer addresses the following aspect of the question:

> How the Deserialization library add new DataColumnGetResponse objects
>   to this immutable list?

Let us consider a simplified version of the problem:

```
JsonMethods.parse("""[1,2,3]""").extract[List[Int]]
```

How does json4s deserialise `[1,2,3]` into immutable `List[Int]`? First it [parses](https://github.com/json4s/json4s#parsing-json) the raw string into an intermediary AST (abstract syntax tree) data structure where it represents the list like so

```
case class JArray(arr: List[JValue]) extends JValue
```

We see here that `arr` is an immutable list. The key line that builds it up after `parse` executes is in [`JsonParser`](https://github.com/json4s/json4s/blob/961c4a6bae0d164e243d25780cad4b5b816bf3f5/native/src/main/scala/org/json4s/native/JsonParser.scala#L176)

```
    def newValue(v: JValue): Unit = {
      ...
        case a: JArray => vals.replace(JArray(v :: a.arr))
      ...
    }
```

Note how the operator [`::`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#::[B%3E:A](elem:B):List[B]) in `v :: a.arr` adds an element at the beginning of this list and returns a **new** list with `v` added in. This means since there are three elements in `[1,2,3]` the following three lists are created by json4s in the process of deserialisation

```
JArray(List(JInt(1))
JArray(List(JInt(2), JInt(1)))
JArray(List(JInt(3), JInt(2), JInt(1)))
```

Again note these are three **separate** lists.

Next, after internal AST is created, actual [deserialisation](https://github.com/json4s/json4s#extracting-values) to `List[Int]` takes place by calling `extract[List[Int]]`. The key component that does this for lists is [`CollectionBuilder`](https://github.com/json4s/json4s/blob/c38dac202be73c084c7cc371dcdf1f335b3d9583/core/src/main/scala/org/json4s/Extraction.scala#L434)

```
  private class CollectionBuilder(json: JValue, tpe: ScalaType)(implicit formats: Formats) {
    ...
      val array: Array[_] = json match {
        case JArray(arr)      => arr.map(extractDetectingNonTerminal(_, typeArg)).toArray
    ...
    }
```

Note how we simply map over AST `arr` built up during parsing step and convert each element to the model of type `typeArg`, which in our simple case is `Int` but in your case would be `DataColumnGetResponse`.

Comment: thanks for the detailed explanation.doesnt these immutable lists cause unnecessary space complexity?

Comment: @AshikaUmangaUmagiliya We may trade some of the efficiency for correctness. For example, immutable structures are more likely to be thread safe. Consider exploring [immutability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/immutability?tab=Votes) tag for advantages and disadvantages of immutability.

Answer (score 4):

Answer the first one:

An immutable object can be mutated with the `copy` function:

```
dataSet.copy(columns = newResp :: dataSet.columns)
```

For more complex tasks you can use *Lenses* see for example here: [enter link description here](https://github.com/softwaremill/quicklens)

Answer the second one:

If it is a reserved word you can do it like

```
case class ColumnResponse (id: String, name: String, `type`: String)
```